# What are the benefits of the async versions of the jws APIs?

Tags: javascript, streaming, jwt

[jws](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jws) offers both sync and async versions of several of the functions it provides.

What async work is being done in the async versions?

For example, this is how [`createSign`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jws#jwscreatesignoptions) is used:

```js
jws.createSign({
  header: { alg: 'RS256' },
  privateKey: privateKeyStream,
  payload: payloadStream,
}).on('done', function(signature) {
  // ...
});
```

From peeking at the source and the source of the dependencies, I can't figure it out. Some reasons for making an API async are:

- to not buffer input in memory
- to offload work to a worker
- to implement part of the functionality in Wasm

I couldn't find any of these things happening.

The core of the work seems to be happening in [`jwa`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwa#example), which, as far as I can tell is synchronous:

```js
const signature = hmac.sign(input, secret);
hmac.verify(input, signature, secret) // === true;
```

Is the streamy API there just for convenience, when the input is a readable stream instead of a string? Is what's going on effectively the same as (pseudocode): `streamToPromise(readableStream).then(str => createSignSync(str))`? Or is there genuine async work that jws is doing for us that I'm missing somehow?